# Programming the serial description

Tags: serial, usb, python, windows

Is it possible to program a custom description so that my python program can know exactly what USB port to connect to for that specific programming?

It should be able to find any board with that program so the best approach is if a custom description can be programmed with the active program being uploaded.

I want to make sure my setup can handle multiple Arduino boards and always know what USB to use for each specific use.

This finds a general Arduino device:

```
for port in serial.tools.list_ports.comports():
    if "Arduino" in port.description:
        print "Arduino device!"
```

But I want something like this:

```
for port in serial.tools.list_ports.comports():
    if "proximity_sensor" in port.description:
        print "My specific Arduino program!"
```

Comment: Use the `serial_number` parameter to find a specific board?

Comment: Yes, this will find one specific board. What I want is to find a series of boards with a specific programming. I will update my initial question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a normal Arduino board, no, it's not possible from a sketch POV. With a Leonardo or similar ATMega32U4 based board it may be possible to give it a unique VID/PID combination, and even possibly custom manufacturer and product strings. You may be able to do it by creating a custom board definition in boards.txt (or maybe manipulation of the AVR core) - but I have never tried that sort of thing with Arduino, so I cannot vouch for how easy it would be.

However (*shameless self-promotion coming here...*) if you were to switch away from Arduino and use a chipKIT board like the Lenny (or any of the other chipKIT boards with a direct USB connection, such as the Fubarino boards) then it is possible to craft a completely custom USB profile from within your sketch, including VID/PID, Manufacturer and Product strings, and even what devices the board implements. For example:

```
USBFS usbDevice;
USBManager USB(usbDevice, 0xf055, 0x1234, "Espentech", "My Little Widget");
CDCACM USBSerial;

void setup() {
    USB.addDevice(USBSerial);
    USB.begin();
}

void loop() {
    USBSerial.println(millis());
    delay(1000);
}
```

Which results in:

```
[  661.328155] usb 2-1.2.7: new full-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[  661.458613] usb 2-1.2.7: New USB device found, idVendor=f055, idProduct=1234
[  661.458616] usb 2-1.2.7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  661.458619] usb 2-1.2.7: Product: My Little Widget
[  661.458621] usb 2-1.2.7: Manufacturer: Espentech
[  661.458623] usb 2-1.2.7: SerialNumber: CK2660A05312F3
[  661.459181] cdc_acm 2-1.2.7:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```